# Cascade Dropdown in ASP Net Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a cascading dropdown using jQuery and Ajax in ASP.NET Core 3.1, but cannot seem to come to a solution.

These are my model classes:

```
public class CountryStateViewModel
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}
```

These are my controller methods:

```
public ActionResult DropDown()
{
    List<Country> CountryList = new List<Country> { new Country { CountryId = 1, CountryName = "Sweden" }, new Country { CountryId = 2, CountryName = "Norway" } };
    ViewBag.CountryList = new SelectList(CountryList, "CountryId", "CountryName");
    return View();
}

public JsonResult GetStateList(int CountryId)
{
    List<State> StateList = new List<State> { new State { StateId=1,CountryId = 1, StateName = "Stockholm" }, new State { CountryId = 1, StateName = "Malmö", StateId=2 } };
    return Json(StateList);
}
```

This is my view with script:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        @if (ViewBag.CountryList != null)
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, ViewBag.CountryList as SelectList, "--Select Country--", new { @class = "form-control" })
        }
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, new SelectList(" "), "--Select State--", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

<script src="~/https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CountryId").change(function () {
            $.get("/Forum/GetStateList", { CountryId: $("#CountryId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#StateId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#StateId").append("<option value='" + row.StateId + "'>" + row.StateName + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Finally, I have tried to configure my startup.cs in the following way so that it handles sending the JSON objects:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

I have not been able to make this work. I wonder if the issue is with calling on the script? These are the errors I see under the Console tab in Developer Tools in Chrome:

```
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
jquery.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
jquery.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

When I start the view I can see the two dropdowns but when I pick a country no states are shown in the second dropdown (just two options stating undefined).

Comment: Sorry! I am using .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you have ~?  ```$.get("~/Forum/GetStateList",```

Comment: Unfortunately not :/. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It took a bit of back and forth but I thought I would share what I did in case anyone else runs into a similar issue. This is how I altered my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#CountryId").change(function () {
                $.get("GetStateList", { CountryId: $("#CountryId").val() }, function (data) {
                    $("#StateId").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                        $("#StateId").append("<option value='" + row.StateId + "'>" + row.StateName + "</option>")
                    });
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
```

The only changed I made was to the $.get. I used the Developer Tools to check where I was actually directed too. The second change I did was to the was controller:

```
public JsonResult GetStateList(int CountryId)
        {
            List<State> StateList = new List<State>();

            if (CountryId == 1)
            {
                StateList = new List<State> { new State { StateId = 1, CountryId = 1, StateName = "Stockholm" }, new State { CountryId = 1, StateName = "Malmö", StateId = 2 }, new State { CountryId = 1, StateId = 3, StateName = "Göteborg" } };
            }
             else
                StateList = new List<State> { new State { StateId = 1, CountryId = 1, StateName = "Oslo" }};

            return Json(StateList, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());
    }
```

Here the change I made was to  the return line by adding

```
 new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
```